# Unable to display the tax owed results correctly

Tags: c#, methods, sorting, compareto

Everything seems to run fine, except the tax owed displayed is always 0. I cannot figure out how to correctly get the calculations for the default or the users entries. here is the code I have any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestApp
{
class Rates
{
    public readonly int incomeLimit;
    public readonly double lowTax;
    public readonly double highTax;

    public Rates()
    {
        incomeLimit = 30000;
        lowTax = .15;
        highTax = .28;
    }
    public Rates(int limit, double lowRate, double highRate)
    {
        limit = incomeLimit;
        lowRate = lowTax;
        highRate = highTax;
    }
    public double CalcTax(double income)
    {            
        double tax; 
        if (income < incomeLimit)
        tax = income * lowTax;
        else
            tax = income * highTax;

        return tax;
    }
}
class Taxpayer : IComparable <Taxpayer>
{
    public string social;
    public double grossincome;
    public double taxowed;

    public string SSN 
    { 
        get
    {
        return social;
    }
        set
    {
        social = value;
    }
    }
    public double grossIncome 
    { 
        get
        {
            return grossincome;
        }
        set
        {
            grossincome = value;
        }
    }
    public double taxOwed
    {
        get
        {
            return taxowed;
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(Taxpayer o)
    {           
        return this.taxOwed.CompareTo(o.taxOwed);
    }
    public static void getRates()
    {
        Rates rates = new Rates();
        Taxpayer tax = new Taxpayer();

        int limit = 0;
        double lowRate = 0;
        double highRate = 0;
        char input;
        Console
          .Write("Do you want default values (enter D) or enter your own (enter O)? ");
        input = Char.ToUpper(Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine()));

        switch (input)
        {
            case 'D':
                Rates def = new Rates();
                limit = def.incomeLimit;
                lowRate = def.lowTax;
                highRate = def.highTax;
                tax.taxowed = def.CalcTax(tax.grossIncome);
                break;
            case 'O':
                Rates own = new Rates(limit, lowRate, highRate);
                Console.Write("Enter the dollar limit ");
                limit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter the low rate ");
                lowRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter the high rate ");
                highRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                tax.taxowed = own.CalcTax(tax.grossIncome);
                break;
        }

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Taxpayer[] taxarray = new Taxpayer[5];

        for (int x = 0; x < taxarray.Length; ++x)
        {
            taxarray[x] = new Taxpayer();
            Console.Write("Enter Social Security Number for taxpayer {0}: ", x+1);
            taxarray[x].SSN = Console.ReadLine().Replace("-", "");

            Console.Write("Enter gross income for taxpayer {0}: ", x+1);
            taxarray[x].grossIncome = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            //Taxpayer.getRates();
            Taxpayer.getRates();
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < taxarray.Length; i++)
        {               
            Console.WriteLine("Taxpayer # {0} SSN: {1} income {2:c} Tax is {3:c}", 
              i+1,taxarray[i].SSN, taxarray[i].grossIncome, taxarray[i].taxOwed);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------");
        Array.Sort(taxarray);
        for (int i = 0; i < taxarray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Taxpayer # {0} SSN: {1} income {2:c} Tax is {3:c}", 
              i+1,taxarray[i].SSN, taxarray[i].grossIncome, taxarray[i].taxOwed);
        }            
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? VS has one built-in.

Comment: @I4V: he might be a beginner programmer. Nothing wrong with that, lol...

Comment: @code4life So you say you like reading wall of text. Then please post an answer instead of replying comments. *lol....*

Comment: @I4V: no, I don't like reading wall of text. But nothing wrong with that either. Everyone has to start somewhere, and beginners have the right to ask dumb questions and post walls of text. At least, in the beginning. Come on, man, this user has only 9 points. Let him at least enjoy participating here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem appears to be that you're calling a static method (`getRates`). The values you enter get stored in the newly-created `TaxPayer` instance in that method, but they never get copied to the instance that you're creating in the array.

I think you want to make that an instance method and in your input loop call it like this:

```
taxarray[x].getRates();
```

That will require some changes to your `getRates` method, in particular having it use the `this` reference rather than creating a new `TaxPayer` instance.